# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, bigdata

```java
package RDD_Programing

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDD_Programing {
  def main (args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val spark=SparkSession.builder().master(master = "local")
      .appName(name = "rdd programing").getOrCreate()

    val  sc=spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("OFF")

    val input_path="input/readme/txt"
    val output_path=""

    val rdd1= sc.textFile(input_path)
    val rdd2= rdd1.flatMap(_.split(""))
    val rdd3= rdd2.map(x=>(x,x.length))
    val rdd4= rdd3.filter{case (x,y) => y >=6}

  rdd4.collect().foreach(f=>{
    println(f)
  })
  }
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x4c2bb6e0) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x4c2bb6e0
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
    at RDD_Programing.RDD_Programing$.main(RDD_Programing.scala:8)
    at RDD_Programing.RDD_Programing.main(RDD_Programing.scala)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError solved

Answer (score 0):

check java version. it will not work with java 11/17. it is working with jdk1.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).